# Cannot connect to a new GCP VM created using the snapshot over a HTTPS web server

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, https, google-compute-engine

I have been using a GCP VM for a web server (Windows Server 2016) with https enabled. Now I wish to restore / replicate that https-protected web server in a NEW region with the snapshot created from the existing VM.

The new VM is created fine in the new region from the GCP console, but when I want to have access to this VM using the auto-assigned external IP (with Remote Desktop Connection), it displays an error saying the new VM cannot be connected.

I wonder if this is to do with the https enabled on the existing VM? Should I make a fresh snapshot for the existing web server after disabling or removing https?

Thank you very much.

Comment: In my case it turned out that I did not configure the GCP filrewall properly--the new VM, I created did not have the network tags, which were connected to the firewall rules. Writing just in case someone lands on this page trying to figure out why the machine is up, but no RDP connection could be made.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the snapshot with VSS enabled? If yes, you need to clear the the read-only flag on the volume before creating the instance as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-persistent-disk-snapshot#restrictions):

> When you take a VSS snapshot, Windows marks the volume as read-only during the VSS proccess. If you want to create an instance from a VSS enabled snapshot you must clear the read-only flag on the volume.